# mvc 5 DateTime error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I need to save date from webpage as date and time, but I have an error

> The field FileCreatedOn must be a date" when try to save data as date and time ("2015-05-29 1:28:45 PM").

In DB the field is DateTime; description in Model is

```
public System.DateTime FileCreatedOn { get; set; }
```

in Edit.cshtml file:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileCreatedOn , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                  
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileCreatedOn , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I can read data from DB as Date and time ("2015-05-29 1:28:45 PM") but have an error if try to save it.
Thanks

Comment: try convert in client side  to  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your client side validators are using properly cultures/globalization. If you are using jQuery validate plugin with MVC, see this extension to help modify that plugin to meet your needs: http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html

Comment: Thank you kspearrin, but cultures/globalization doesn't work for this case ((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem standard validation algorithm for client side. I just turned off client side validation for this field (FileCreatedOn) and now all working properly !